# Java repaint firing from non-EDT is slow

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

I'm calling `repaint()` on a Swing component in a JFrame in a thread which is not the EDT (as opposed to a typical `repaint` call in a Swing listener/adapter/actionmap).  Technically, its being called in a callback from the javax.sound.midi `Reciever`, but I don't think this is any different from the general case.

The component is slow to update.  This toy code shows a `JLabel` whose text should be immediately updated to the current time, then we `repaint`, then we print to stdout the current time.  On my system, the label and stdout times *look* proper -- the label `repaint` happens a few millis earlier than the stdout.  However, the label *visually* doesn't update for some time, seemingly a random amount up to even a half second.  When it does update, it displays a sensible time, but an old one.

Performing the [update display time, repaint, print time] test from within the callback of a mouse listener (or key listener etc.) works fine, latency is low.  Of course calling `repaint` only schedules it to happen, but shouldn't the behaviour be the same, especially if wrapped in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`?  Is there an event priority or simple threading fact that I'm missing?  What component is taking long to repaint if not the `JLabel`?  In summary, how can I invoke `repaint` from a non Swing, non-EDT thread?

Non working solutions:

- calling `paintComponent` directly as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9004806/14495758 ; I shouldn't have to implement a custom `JFrame`, right?
- calling `paintImmediately` as in [repaint() in Java doesn't "re-paint" immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13453331/repaint-in-java-doesnt-re-paint-immediately) ; this results in the same behaviour, calls to `repaint` are not being collected and called later
- calling `repaint` on the `JFrame`; this results in the same behaviour

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;import javax.swing.*;import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
public class Main {
    public static String time() {return (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)+"."+(System.currentTimeMillis()%1000);}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame w = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("hey");
        Transmitter tr = MidiUtil.firstTransmitterExcept("gervill","real time sequencer");//makes a MidiDevice and returns its transmitter
        tr.setReceiver(new Receiver(){public void send(final MidiMessage message,final long t) {
                try {
                    label.setText(time());
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(()->{label.paintImmediately(0,0,label.getWidth(),label.getHeight());});
                }catch(final InterruptedException ie) {}catch(final InvocationTargetException ite) {}
                System.out.println(time());
        }public void close() {}});
        w.add(label);
        w.pack();
        w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        w.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for reading.

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't be modifying the labels text out side of the EDT.  `repaint` may re-schedule a paint pass on the EDT, depending on it's own determination of what needs to be done.  Generally I'd not consider trying to get one-to-one update between any thread and the EDT.  A `SwingWorker` may be a better choice, but might need some tweaking to get it to work reasonably well

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, updating on the EDT is something I missed.  Thanks for the suggestion to use `SwingWorker`, but that fails too (polling in `doInBackground` and using `process` to update the ui) -- the issue seems to be deeper in Swing.  Currently looking in the debugger, hopefully that reveals the lag.

Comment: I think, one of the things you need to appreciate is, `repaint` isn't immediate, it's scheduled.  So, if you're updating the UI a lot, you could just be starving the thread

Comment: A [mre] that compiles and demonstrates the problem (or a simpler but similar one) would be helpful.  Note, midi's have their own set of issues so a different example would be best.